# How to define structured attribute in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In my ER-Model is a structured attribute.
the attribute *`user`* has amongst other things a *`authentification`* attribute. this *`athentification`* attribute is linked to other attributes: *`algo`*, *`salt`*, *`hash`* and *`stretch`*.

*`Salting`* and *`hashing`* are ways to kind of protect a password, right?

But how do I define that these attributes are linked to the attribute *`authentification`* and all are part of the table `user`?

my code:

```
CREATE TABLE [user]
(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY
LastLogin Time,
Admin BIT, 
Email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,

-- "auth" for "authentification" 
auth algo CHECK(algo='sha1' OR algo='sha256'),
auth stretch INT,
auth salt VARCHAR(32),
auth hash VARCHAR(24)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should normalize that and move the authentication type into a separate table that is referenced by the `user` table:

```
create table auth_type
(
   id        integer primary key,
   algorithm varchar(10) not null,
   stretch   integer  not null
   salt      VARCHAR(32) not null
   hash      VARCHAR(24) not null, 
   constraint check_algo CHECK(algo='sha1' OR algo='sha256')
);

CREATE TABLE [user]
(
  ID        INT PRIMARY KEY
  LastLogin datetime2, -- I think only a time is probably not enough
  Admin     BIT, 
  Email     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  auth_id   integer not null, 
  foreign key fk_user_auth (auth_id) references auth(id)
);
```

Comment: thank you. could you tell me where i can check the hierarchy of the attributes in sql server management studio 2014? (to make sure the connection worked the way it's represented in my ER-Modell)

Comment: and hashing and salting is for protecting the password (->kryptology), right? so now with this code this is all i need for the hashing and salting or would i need something else?

Comment: Sorry I don't use SSMS - the attributes salt and hash were suggested by you. I don't know what you want to do with that

Comment: oh ok no problem, i got these from my prof. guess we'll get them explained next lesson. but thank you for your help: it works!

Comment: @noclue123 _Salt_ is a base value used by the hashing algorithm. By starting the hashing of each password from a different value for each user it helps to thwart dictionary attacks, i.e. you would need a dictionary for each salt value. _Hash_ is the value stored after hashing the user's password. It cannot be (practically) turned back into a password. Instead, when a user attempts to authentificate _[sic]_ the password they supply is combined, via the hashing algorithm, with the salt and the resulting value is compared to the stored hash. A match indicates goodness.